# An integral related to the theory of isotropic harmonic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, integration

The classical Hamiltonian for an isotropic harmonic oscillator in polar coordinates is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
H = \frac{1}{2m}\left(p_\rho^2 + \frac{p_\varphi^2}{\rho^2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\rho^2,
\end{equation}
where $m$ is the mass and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. The action variable is
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
J_\rho = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}d\rho\sqrt{2mE - \frac{\beta_\varphi^2}{\rho^2} - (m\omega)^2\rho^2},
\end{equation}
where $\rho_{1,2}$ are the turning points of the oscillator and $\beta_\varphi$ is the constant action $J_\varphi$. They are the positive roots of the equation
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
2mE - \frac{\beta_\varphi^2}{\rho^2} - (m\omega^2)^2\rho^2 = 0.
\end{equation}
How to show that the integral evaluates to
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}d\rho\sqrt{a - \frac{b^2}{\rho^2} - c^2\rho^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{a}{2c} - |b|\right)?
\end{equation}

This equation is reported in H. Iro's book *A Modern Approach to Classical Mechanics*, (2016).

Comment: Evaluating integrals is math, not physics. This belongs on Math SE.

Comment: What have you tried in order to solve the integral?

Comment: Thanks @Eli, that was my first thought but it seems that evaluates to $tan^{-1}$ and therefore it needs a clever trigonometric substitution. The $\pi/2$ comes from $\tan^{-1}(\infty)$ when the integral is evaluated at the turning points. I tried to coax something from Wolfram but it didn't reveal the steps and I am unable to get the $|b|$ factor.

Answer (score 0):

I obtain this result ?

I )

$$J_r=\frac 1\pi\int \sqrt{F}\,dr\quad,
F=-{\frac {{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}}{{r}^{2}}}-{r}^{2}{c}^{2}+a$$

II)

$$ \text{result}=\left(J\right)_r\bigg|_{r_l}^{r_h}={\rm signum} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2\,a-2\,\sqrt {{a}^{2
}-4\,{c}^{2}{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}}}}{c}} \right) 
\,P_{{\varphi }}=\pm P_{{\varphi }} =\text{constant}$$

where $~r_l~,~r_h~$ are the negative and positive solutions of $~F(r)=0$

$$r_l = \sqrt{\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4P_\varphi^2c^2}}{2c^2}} \\
r_h = \sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4P_\varphi^2c^2}}{2c^2}}
$$

**Remark**

It is not Elliptic Integral. I obtained the result with MAPLE program

Maple result

$$\begin{eqnarray}\pi\,J_r &=&\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {-{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-{r}^{4}{c}^{2}+a{r}^{2}} - \\
 & & \frac{1}{4c}\,a\tan^{-1} \left( -{\frac {{r}^{2}c}{\sqrt {-{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-{r}^{4}
{c}^{2}+a{r}^{2}}}}+\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {a}{c\sqrt {-{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-{r}^
{4}{c}^{2}+a{r}^{2}}}} \right) + \\
& & \frac{1}{4}\,P_{{\varphi }}\pi + iP_{{\varphi }}\ln(r) - \\
& & \frac{1}{2}\,i
P_{{\varphi }}\ln  \left( 2\,i{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-ia{r}^{2}+2\,P_{{
\varphi }}\sqrt {-{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-{r}^{4}{c}^{2}+a{r}^{2}}
 \right)
& & 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

hence
$$\pi\,\frac {\partial\,J_r}{\partial r}=
{\frac {\sqrt {-{P_{{\varphi }}}^{2}-{r}^{4}{c}^{2}+a{r}^{2}}}{r}}=\sqrt{F}$$

Comment: Strangely, wolframalpha gives a different answer. For notational simplicity if $R(x) = ax^2 - b - cx^4$ then wolframalpha says $$\begin{equation}\int \frac{\sqrt{R(x)}}{x}dx = \frac{\sqrt{R(x)}}{2} - 2\sqrt{b}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{ax^2 - 2b}{2\sqrt{bR(x)}}\right) - \frac{a}{\sqrt{c}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a - 2cx^2}{2\sqrt{cR(x)}}\right)\end{equation}$$

Comment: @AmeyJoshi if you differentiate  the above result you don't obtain $~R(x)=F(x)~$ ? see my neu edit

Comment: thanks for the edit. I'll evaluate it at the limits and confirm if it is right. (I made minor edits to the expression in the interest of readability, hope you won't mind.)

Comment: I'll redo the calculation again but I am getting an extra factor of $1/2$ and an extra term $\begin{equation} -\frac{ib}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2b}{r^2} - a\right)\end{equation}$. I think, we are getting closer :-).

Comment: I think we are close to treating your expression as the correct answer if we take care of the last factor :-) in my analysis below. I posted it separately because it was substantial and I didn't want to edit your answer to that extent.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not yet and answer but a continuation of @Eli's analysis**.

At the turning points, $-P_\varphi^2 - r^4c^2 + ar^2 = 0$. The turning points themselves are
\begin{equation}
 r^2 = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4P_\varphi^2c^2}}{2c^2}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
 2r^2c^2 - a = \pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4P_\varphi^2c^2}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, at the turning point $r_h$, the argument of $\tan^{-1}$ is $-\infty$ while that of
$r_l$ is $+\infty$. Thus,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \pi J_r(r_h) &=& \frac{a}{4}\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{4}
 + iP_\varphi\ln r_h - \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln(i(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2)) \\
  &=& \frac{a\pi}{8c} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{4}
 + iP_\varphi\ln r_h - \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln(e^{i\pi/2}(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2)) \\
  &=& \frac{a\pi}{8c} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{4}
 + iP_\varphi\ln r_h + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{4} - \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2) \\
  &=& \frac{a\pi}{8c} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{2}
 + \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln r_h^2 - \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2) \\
  &=& \frac{a\pi}{8c} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{2}
 + \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln\frac{r_h^2}{2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly,
\begin{equation}
 \pi J_r(r_l) = -\frac{a\pi}{8c} + \frac{P_\varphi\pi}{2} + \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln\frac{r_l^2}{2P_\varphi^2 - ar_l^2}
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
 \pi J_r(r_h) - \pi J_r(r_l) = \frac{a\pi}{4c} + \frac{iP_\varphi}{2}\ln\frac{r_h^2(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_l^2)} {r_l^2(2P_\varphi^2 - ar_h^2)} 
\end{equation}

We are done if we show that the second expression on RHS is equal to
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\pi}{2}|P_\varphi|.
\end{equation}